# Iterating over columns with index

Tags: python, pandas

How I can iterate over columns with index in pandas, for rows we can use `for i, j in df.iterrows():` which will give the index and the row.

Is there anything similar for columns?

```
spice smice skice bike dike mike 
    1     23     35    34   34   56 
    135   34     23    21   56   34
    231   12     67    21   62   75
```

I am trying to use a nested for loop like the following:

```
for index, col1 in  df.columns:
  for col2 in df.columns[index:]:
```

Is there any better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the following solution but not sure whether this is right way of doing this, I'm new to pandas.

```
import pandas as pd 

# initialize list of lists 
data = [['tom', 10], ['nick', 15], ['juli', 14]] 

# Create the pandas DataFrame 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'Age']) 
for ind, column in enumerate(df.columns):
  print(ind, column)
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe you need loop by column names and for `Series` select by column names:

```
for col_name in df.columns:
    print (col_name)
    print (df[col_name])
```

Alternative solution, disadvantage is worse readable:

```
for col_name in df:
    print (col_name)
    print (df[col_name])
```

Your solution is possible with transpose by [`DataFrame.T`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.T.html), but a bit overcomplicated in my opinion:

```
for col_name, s in df.T.iterrows():
    print (col_name)
    print (s)
```

EDIT:

```
for col_name in df.columns:
    print (col_name)
    print (df[col_name])
    print (df.columns.get_loc(col_name))
```

Comment: Where I can get column index in this?

Comment: @Unnikrishnan - Answer was edited for index by col name.